# VLCJ Stream viewing not working

Tags: java, stream, vlcj

I am trying to view a streamed video (for example, this one: rtmp://cp145180.live.edgefcs.net/live/iptv1_1_500@42325) using vlcj's EmbeddedMediaPlayer and I succeed on only one machine; it works on my desktop, doesn't work on my laptop. The systems are:

Desktop: Windows 7 Pro 64-bit (64-bit JVM),
Laptop: Windows 7 Pro 32-bit (32-bit JVM)

I'm using adequate vlc libraries in both cases. On my desktop, the streamed video is viewed just fine, but on my laptop - there is neither video nor audio. And i don't get any errors, just a black screen of the player. Here's the code:

```
public class Player {
private JFrame frame;
private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;
private MessageViewPanel messagePanel;

public Player() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocation(100, 50);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
}

public void play(String mrl) {
    if(mediaPlayerComponent == null) {
        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        mediaPlayerComponent.setLocation(50,50);
        mediaPlayerComponent.setSize(700, 500);
    }

    frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setStandardMediaOptions();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl);
}
}

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
    final Player player = new Player();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            player.play("rtmp://cp145180.live.edgefcs.net/live/iptv1_1_500@42325");
        }
    }.start();
}
}
```

Has anyone of you stumbled across a similar issue?

EDIT: I have another issue. I'm trying to view a streamed video from a network camera. I have the proper url (looks like rtsp://ip_adx/axis-media/media.amp), but it won't play. It behaves the same as on my laptop with any other stream - black screen.

I badly need help with this :P

Comment: is vlc installed on your laptop ???

Comment: yes, it is, and it's the latest version